# Extracting Facebook ID or email from browser's history

Tags: web-browser, forensics, logging, chrome, facebook

While I was looking at my browser's history I noticed there has been a Facebook login from my computer, there are some Facebook related messaging and profile links in my browser history (chrome).

The login was not made using my account, so how can I learn the account information of the logged person (Facebook ID or email address or any other helpful details could give a clue who it might be).

Comment: If you have a gmail account and were logged into it while they logged into the facebook you can try to get the info from Google (it may or may not be on www.google.com/takeout)

Answer (score 2):

You can probably obtain information by looking at the browser cache. When the browser downloads pages, it stores copies of them in local files, so as to speed up operations if asked to inspect the same page again. Whether a specific page will be cached or not depends on what the server says about the page (there are HTTP headers for that); old pages are automatically removed from the cache so that its total size remains low; and the user has the possibility to "clear the cache" manually.

Location of the cache, and its internal format, depend on the browser type and version, and the operating system. If you use Chrome on Windows, [this freeware utility](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html) purports to be able to let you see and navigate the cache contents (I have not tried it and I do not vouch for its quality). Alternatively, go have a look at the files in `[User Profile]\Local Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Cache` where `[User Profile]` is the home directory of your account on the machine (you may have to configure your file explorer to show hidden and system files).

Of course, if someone potentially evil and hostile could use your computer, then he could do a lot of bad things with it, including planting malware which will spy on you and siphon out the contents of all your files and passwords and secrets. However, if the said person used your computer to log on Facebook and left enough traces for you to see it, then chances are that he was not that competent or did not try very hard for concealment.